# int for timer error: Local variable ans defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Tags: java, swing, variables, local

I have some code for a timer as follows:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();

JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Stop Server after X Seconds");
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        int ans = functions.secC();

        Timer t = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setText("Server will shutdown in: "+ans+ "seconds");
                ans--;
            }
        }); 
        t.start();
    }
});
panel.add(btnNewButton);
panel.add(label);
```

And at the `ans--;` line I get this error code:

```
Local variable ans defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final
```

I'm not sure what I should do to fix this error, I've played around with making it final but that doesn't work..

Comment: How did you make it `final`? Post the code that didn't work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define `ans` as `final`;

```
final int ans = functions.secC();
```

But if `ans` isn't needed anywhere else, you could just define it as an instance field of the `Timer`;

```
Timer t = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
    private int ans = functions.secC();
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        label.setText("Server will shutdown in: "+ans+ "seconds");
        ans--;
    }
});
```

But in this case, I'd probably also disable the button, since you really don't have anyway of knowing if the user has already pressed the button or not...